# Javascript sliding menus not working

Tags: javascript, slidingmenu, object-detection

This javascript sliding menu is NOT working--the only error that debugger gives is that the first IF statement is a block command & should have curly braces, which I don't understand.

Does anyone see an obvious error? I'm not sure I'm using 'this' keyword correctly( as well as the variable slideList inside the function showSlide...please help & any feedback on my formatting (white-space) is appreciated as well!

```
window.onload = makeMenus;

var currentSlide = null;
var timeID = null;
var leftPos = 0;

function makeMenus() {
    var slideMenus = new Array();
    var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {
        if (allElems[i].className == "slideMenus") menus.push(allElems[i]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < slideMenus.length; i++) {
        slideMenus[i].onclick = showSlide;
        slideMenus[i].ul.style.left = "0px"; //for each object in slideMenus Array, ref 1st ul       element within that object and set the value of the ul elements left style property to 0px
    }
    document.getElementById("head").onclick = closeSlide;
    document.getElementById("main").onclick = closeSlide;
}

function showSlide() {
    var slideList = this.id + ".ul[0]"; //stores object ref to the 1st ul element nested within the     current object. 

    if (currentSlide !== null) {
        closeSlide();
    } else {
        closeSlide();
        currentSlide = slideList;
        currentSlide.style.display = "block";
        timeID = setInterval("moveSlide()", 1);
    }
}

function closeSlide() {
    if (currentSlide !== null) {
        clearInterval(timeID);
        currentSlide.style.left = "0px";
        currentSlide.style.display = "none";
        currentSlide = null;
    }
}

function moveSlide() {

    if ((leftPos + 5) <= 220) {
        currentSlide.style.left = leftPos + "px"
    } else {
        clearInterval(timeID);
        leftPos = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe give a few minutes of your time and read about it, here for example -> http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/ . It will help you a lot I think, for this problem, and the next ones. ( copied the link form here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var slideList = this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

Answer (score 0):

just taking a look at your code I noticed that you have this line

`var slideList = this.id + ".ul[0]"; //stores object ref to the 1st ul element nested`

It looks like you're trying to grab the first element of the ul array, but since you're putting that in quotes your browser is likely treating that like a string instead. Say this.id was equal to the string "ul-element", this variable will output "ul-element.ul[0]" as a string rather than getting the element at ul[0].

Just out of curiosity, have you looking into using jquery to make your site do this? It would save quite a bit of time and headache, although if you're doing this for a personal project I understand doing it this way :)

-Frank

Comment: yes this is for a short javascript class i'm taking - i'm a beginner!

Comment: the instructions for that line of code are " create a variable named 'slideList' which stores an object reference to the first ul element nested within the current object (as referenced by the 'this' keyword).

Comment: Hey Frank-i think can't figure this out :(

Comment: Hey Vynce, I haven't been online for a few days, sorry I wasn't able to get back to you sooner. I'm not sure if you've already figured this out or had to turn in the project, but I found a couple things that might help out some. I'm not sure if this will help, but here's one way I think might work var element = $('id')
return element.match('ul') ? element : element.up('ul'); This might go past the element you're trying to find, so you could also try the built in .previous function too. I think .up or .previous could get you in the right direction.

Comment: this was the answer, frank-thanks for you help!                                               var slideList = this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];